# invalid_grant error running google app remotely on github actions

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I'm using the [Gmail Tester](https://github.com/levz0r/gmail-tester) app for a dedicated test suite. This requires you to create a google application with Gmail API access in order to use. I set up the app. Locally, I'm able to use a script to auth in and generate tokens, pass them into the client, and use them successfully. But when I try to use those same generated credentials remotely in a Github action, I get the ambiguous `invalid_grant` issue regardless of what the request is:

```
[gmail] Checking for message from 'undefined', to: undefined, contains 'undefined' in subject...
The API returned an error: Error: invalid_grant
Error when getting recent emails: Error: invalid_grant
[gmail] Error: GaxiosError: invalid_grant
    at Gaxios._request (node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/gaxios/src/gaxios.ts:158:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async OAuth2Client.refreshTokenNoCache (node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:178:19)
    at async OAuth2Client.getRequestMetadataAsync (node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:298:17)
    at async OAuth2Client.requestAsync (node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:371:23) {
```

My theory is that Google recognizes that I've generated tokens in one place and attempted to use them in another, but that's mostly conjecture and I can't find anything definitive on the subject. The tokens definitely have not expired; they were generated today.